# Regarding experience

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

> I experienced a weird dream.

The experience means to have and be aware of a particular emotion or physical feeling. When I wrote something, I expressed sentence like the above.

By the way, someone told me that I had better change the expression into 'in dream'.

Isn't the word of 'experience' suitable for the sentence expression?

Answer (score 1):

The most common verbs used with "a dream" are "to have", then "to be". Third on the list is "to dream" but it's much lower:

[image]

"To experience" is not a verb that most native users would choose:

[image]

"dreamed a dream" was used 14 times as often as "experienced a dream" in 2000. "had a dream" was used 360 times as often and together all of the more popular choices in the results were used 1250 times more often as "experienced a dream". Most native speakers would say "I had a weird dream".